# I am having a problem formating a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a piece of code that is giving me trouble

i have the variable Average = 94.56 and and another arbitrary variable student

I am asked to print this variable but in the string i must format it such that instead of 94.56 i get 94.6 when i call the print function so this is what i have

```
print(Student + " " + 'class average was' + " " + str(Average + .04))
```

but i get this ugly number

- Elsa Martinez class average was 94.60000000000001

Why does it do this and how can i just get 94.6

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is rounding.

```
print(Student + " " + 'class average was' + " " + str(round(Average,1)))
```

round(number, digits) method takes two argument, number which is a float that you want to round, digits is the number of digits after decimal place you want to round to, in your case 1 digit

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you get a number slightly higher than the real answer is because of the way most coding languages add floating numbers.

Using the `round()` method will solve your issue in this case.